# slick saving multiple objects

Tags: json, scala, rest, slick

hey i have a react app that sends an order to my api, for example

```
[
    {
        "product_id":13,
        "quantity":2
    },
    {
        "product_id":12,
        "quantity":2
    }
]
```

and what i would like to do with it is, parse that json to Seq[Product]
and here my problem begins i dont know to save that Seq with slick.

```
def createMany(productList: Seq[Product]): Future[Seq[Int]] = db.run {
    for {
      p <- productList
    } yield products += p
  }
```

where products is a TableQuery[Product],
was thinking about something like this, but im getting

```
Type mismatch, expected: DBIOAction[NotInferedR, NoStream, Nothing], actual: Seq[JdbcProfile.this.ProfileAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write]]
```

What im trying to return is a list of ids of products i just inserted

Comment: could you share what is the version of slick you are using? Also, I think when you run db.run{...} this, it will return you Seq[Future[Int]]. If you want to add batch of Product, you need to use ++= instead of +=.

Answer (score 2):

tomcy is right that you need to use `++=` instead of `+=` when inserting a Seq. Also if you want the ids back after the insert you can try:

```
products returning products.map(_.id) ++= productList
```